# Вывод текста, когда курсор находится над формой

Tags: c#, winforms, текст, position, мышь

Задача состоит в следующем: есть форма. Во время того, когда курсор находится **над формой**, и пользователь нажимает **левую кнопку мыши**, в этой точке экрана (где находится курсор) выводится какая-то надпись.

Эта надпись не исчезает пока пользователь держит нажатой левую кнопку мыши. Соответственно, когда отпускает - она исчезает.

**Вопрос в следующем:** какое свойство формы лучше использовать для нажатия кнопки мыши и как именно определить, что курсор находится именно над формой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: пример работы]

```
public partial class FormMain : Form
{
    private Label _label;

    public FormMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.MouseDown += FormMain_MouseDown;
        this.MouseUp += FormMain_MouseUp;
    }
    private void FormMain_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left)
            return;

        _label = new Label();
        _label.Location = e.Location;
        _label.Text = "Какой-то текст";
        this.Controls.Add(_label);
    }

    private void FormMain_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Controls.Remove(_label);
        _label = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: ввел все точно также, однако почему-то при запуске, когда нажимаешь на левую кнопку мыши, надпись появляется, но потом не исчезает

Comment: Значит введен не весь код или введен криво. Метод `FormMain_MouseUp` реализован? Я не могу заглянут к вам через плечо, но вся проблема ваша. Мой код 100% рабочий, демку я записывал с работы этого кода.